# Does UK personal allowance include NIC contributions?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, tax-deduction, national-insurance

I have ended an internship in the UK and am now studying there. I am planning to fill in a P50 form since I earned less than £11,500 and I'm not going to work again during this tax year.

I paid around £800 in income tax and £1,100 in NIC contributions. Am I going to get refunded both, or only the income tax?

In other words, does the £11,500 personal allowance include NIC contributions?

Comment: The question "does the personal allowance include NI contributions" (it does, it's based on income before tax and employee's NI are deducted) is not the same question as "Will my NI contributions be refunded in these circumstances" (I'm not sure, which is why this isn't an answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll only get the income tax refunded. The £11,500 annual personal allowance only applies to income tax.

National Insurance contributions are levied on a weekly/monthly basis (depending on how often you get paid) rather than yearly like income tax, so you aren't entitled to a refund if you stop working part way through the tax year.